# What vegan alternative to hydrating/repair creams are there?

Tags: veganism, health

Due to the cold temperatures, my hands are drying and chapping a bit. I'm using a cream to repair my hands. But, since I'm beginning with veganism, I looked at its composition and I saw it contains *glycerin* and *stearic acid* (maybe among others).

- So, I would like to know if there is a vegan alternative to those creams.
- Can an essential oil be used to replace it?
  *I'm totally new about that, but I'm very interested in it. That's why I'm asking if it could be an alternative (while being totally open to other alternatives).*

Comment: Glycerin can be vegan. What country are you living in? E.g. in Germany or the UK, it's very easy to find creams that are labelled as vegan.

Comment: @Turion I'm living in France.

Comment: Then you'll certainly find hydrating creams labelled as vegan in organic shops, and even in some super markets (as far as I remember from my last visit).

Comment: In Germany, large drugstores will usually have a few brands each of hand cream, toothpaste, shampoo, foam bath ... that are vegan. Supermarkets, not always.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both of those ingredients may be from plant sources (for example, cacao and shea butters both contain stearic acid).

Producers of cosmetics are getting better at labelling for vegans. I advise you to check the labels of a range of products; many companies produce vegan moisturisers.

You can also use single-ingredient products like cocoa butter or shea butter, or make your own moisturisers with a mixture of plant oils and butters (almond oil works quite well for me)

I myself have very dry hands and feet and I use products from [yaoh](http://www.yaoh.co.uk), [PHB](http://www.phbethicalbeauty.co.uk/) and Lush as I'm mostly too lazy to make my own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you're talking about oil, is it the same as essential oil or not at all?

Comment: @Niitaku when I talk about oil here I mean (generally liquid) fats - things like nut and seed oils such as almond oil, rapeseed oil, coconut oil. Essential oils in my understanding are powerful volatile oils extracted from plants in tiny amounts, such as jasmine, tea tree etc. Those oils may have healing properties (lavender, for example), but they are too strong to use undiluted, and it would be prohibitively expensive to use them in large amounts. I usually make a massage oil with 100ml almond oil ("base oil") and about ten drops of jasmine/geranium/patchouli/ylang ylang essential oil