# Are there certification labels that ensure a product is really vegan?

Tags: veganism, labeling

It could depend on country legislation, but I saw that some products that claim to be organic can not be at 100%. This is very frequent in hypermarkets/superstores with products of their own brand to be cheaper than competitors while still having the certification label *organic*.

As I understood, [some ingredients can be obtained either from animal and from plants](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/263/77).

- Could it be the same about vegan products?
- Is there local or worldwide certification labels that ensure a product is really vegan?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Could it be the same about vegan products?

Well, yes. Corruption is something that has always existed among us humans. There is nothing we can do to be 100% sure, all we can is learn from our mistakes and do better.

> Is there local or worldwide certification labels that ensure a product is really vegan?

The Vegan Action Foundation has a label for vegan products used for 700+ companies. [Here is the process to obtain the certification](https://vegan.org/certification-process/).

[image]

Cruelty Free international has a similar label for animal-free testing, used for 600+ companies. [This is their certification process](https://web.archive.org/web/20190704223725/https://www.crueltyfreeinternational.org/what-we-do/corporate-partnerships/leaping-bunny-certification-programme). Note that a cruelty-free certified product is not necessarily vegan, and, in fact, it is not even necessarily cruelty-free yet (but has agreed to stop all animal abuse and to submit to independent audits).

[image]
<sub>(source: [crueltyfreeinternational.org](https://www.crueltyfreeinternational.org/sites/default/files/sidebar-section-image/LeapingBunny_1.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Could you explain what the Cruelty Free International certification means a bit more? What do they define "animal abuse" as?

Comment: To what extent are these labels more trustworthy than others? Is the problem really corruption rather than fraud or green-washing?

Comment: In my experience most of the products marked with 'certified vegan' are vegan, but there are exceptions so you need to read the ingredients or deep dive.
The products marked with 'Cruelty free' are not cruelty free as nobody is really checking/validating them and they also contain animal products.